# in any triangle abc prove that bisectors of the interior angle A and the exterior angles at B and C are concurrent

Tags: geometry

i assumed the exterior angles meet at point D, then joined A with D and tried proving AD is angle bisector of angle A. 
But i cant get to the proof. any idea will be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is enough to consider that a bisector (internal or external) of the angle made by two distinct lines $\ell_1,\ell_2$ meeting at some point $P$ is (part of) the locus of points $Q$ for which $d(Q,\ell_1)=d(Q,\ell_2)$.

If some point $Q$ belongs to the external angle bisector through $B$ **and** to the external angle bisector through $C$, it fulfills
$$ d(Q,BA) = d(Q,BC) = d(Q,CA) $$
so by $d(Q,BA)=d(Q,CA)$, it belongs to the internal angle bisector through $A$, too.

Comment: Just to be clear, $d(Q,AB)$ stands for the distance of $Q$ from the $AB$-line.

Comment: got it. nice approach

Answer (score 0):

we construct a parallel line to BC that passes through A and a parallel line to BC that passes through C, we obtain

A parallelogram ABCD.

Consider triangles ABC and ADC

ÐADC º ÐABC.  So, the angle bisectors are the same. We know that the angle bisectors of a triangle are concurrent.  So, the bisectors of ÐABC, ÐDAC, and ÐDCA are concurrent.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the triangle, $ABC$
Then, Let each of the angles be the following,
for $\angle B = \alpha$
for $\angle C = \beta$
so, exterior of each will be $180-\alpha$ and $180-\beta$ respectively
and the bisected ones will be, $90-\alpha$ and $90-\beta$ respectively
so the interior angle, that is, $\angle A = 180-(\alpha + \beta)$, so its bisected angle is, $90-(\alpha + \beta)$
so, now, when we see the angle between the line $AB$ and the point $D$ as taken by you, where they will intersect, it is always $90$ so, now the angle formed, at the point, of the intersection, of the bisector of $\angle A$ and the intersection of the line $BC$ it will be, $\alpha + \beta$ which will be same for the triangle, $ACD$, i.e., the triangle, on the other part, so, by $ASA$ both are congruent, so they will form a parallelogram, so the lines, $BD$ and $CD$ both intersect to form a vertex, $D$, so they will intersect, same can be said, for $AD$ which will be its diagonal, so the three are surely concurrent